# Не добавляются в MySQL данные  (ошибка в запросе)

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем!

Не могу добавить в базу $tab_data - где моя ошибка? Делал даже так `('".$tab_data."')`

```
<?
$tab_data=iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8",$imgtake );
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tab(depart) VALUES ('$tab_data')");
?>
```

Comment: ошибку какую-нить выдает ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tab_data=iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8",$imgtake);
$tab_data=mysql_real_escape_string($tab_data); // <--
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tab(depart) VALUES ('$tab_data')");
```

Answer (score 2):

Если выдает ошибку аля "*Duplicate entry '' for key и т.д.*", то сделайте пробел между tab и (depart) или же возьмите название таблицы и поля в обратные кавычки, а лучше и то, и другое:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tab` (`depart`) VALUES ('$tab_data')");
```

Вариант номер два - у вас добавляется запись, но в поле depart пусто. Тогда возникает вопрос: а надо ли преобразовывать строку в другую кодировку? Потому как это может быть именно из-за этого.